# What is the meaning of $f^{\left(n\right)}\left(x\right)\:-the\:n^{th}\:derivative$?

Tags: derivatives, pattern-recognition

For example, If I had to calculate the first, second and third derivative of $f(x)=\frac{1}{x-1}$

I would find that they would be the following:

$$f^{'}(x)=-\frac{1}{\left(x-1\right)^2}$$
$$f^{''}(x)=\frac{2}{\left(x-1\right)^3}$$
$$f^{3}(x)=-\frac{6}{\left(x-1\right)^4}$$

Seeing this pattern, I want to understand what $f^{\left(n\right)}\left(x\right)\:-the\:n^{th}\:derivative$ means in relation to this pattern.

Comment: Imagine you were shown a sequence $a_n=1, -1, 2, -6, 24, \cdots$ with the first term corresponding to the index of $n=0$.   Could you find an expression for $n$?  Can you arrive at a single expression for all the different orders of derivatives of $f(x)$?

Comment: It is easy to show by induction that $f^{(n)}(x)= \frac{(-1)^{n}n!}{(1-x)^{n+1}}$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The nth derivative has the same meaning as, say, the fourth derivative, except that in this case $n $ could be *any* arbitrary natural number. To find an nth derivative you need to observe a pattern in the derivatives, and if you're feeling cautious of your choice, prove it by induction.

Here, we have an oscillating negative sign, where the negatives show up on the odd terms. This implies the existence of $(-1)^n$ in the nth derivative.

Carrying on in a similar fashion, I obtained $$f^{(n)}(x) = (-1)^n \frac{n!}{(x-1)^{n+1}}$$

Do you see *why* this answer works?

By all means, prove it!

Answer (score 3):

**Hint**. Assume $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$ and  $\alpha \ne 0$. One may prove by a direct recurrence
$$
\left(u^\alpha\right)^{(k)}:=\frac{d^k}{du^k}\left(u^\alpha\right)=\alpha (\alpha-1)\cdots (\alpha-k+1)\cdot u^{\alpha-k}, \qquad k=0,1, \cdots.
$$ By putting
$$
u=x-1,\quad \alpha=-1, \quad k=n,
$$ one gets here

> $$
> f^{(n)}(x)= (-1)^{n} \cdot\frac{n!}{(x-1)^{n+1}}
> $$

with $f(x)= \dfrac{1}{(x-1)}$.

Answer (score 0):

yes $$f^{(n)}(x)$$ means the n-th derivative. i think it must be $$f^{(n)}(x)=(-1)^{(n)}n!(x-1)^{-(n+1)}$$

Comment: why the $-1$? what is wrong?

Comment: Well, I think it's because you have an extra $2$ in the exponent of $(-1)$.

Comment: $2n+1$ is always odd, so $(-1)^{2n+1} = -1$ for all $n$. For a counter example to this result, see the problem statement for $n = 2$.

Comment: i know this but it was only a typo